# Changed upon the blue guitar?

Tags: prepositions, poetry

I had seen the following excerpt from [this poem](http://www.artic.edu/aic/collections/resource/291) in a rhetoric workbook a while ago as an example of a word construction:

> They said, "You have a blue guitar, 
>   You do not play things as they are."
>
> The man replied, "Things as they are /
>   Are changed upon the blue guitar."

My question is regarding the use of the word "upon" in the last line.  Is this usage ever correct, or is this just an example of creative license in poetry?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ah, one of my favorite poets. Stevens uses an extensive and sometimes recondite vocabulary, but he is one of the last poets I would accuse of poor grammar.

Just remember that [*on* and *upon* are synonyms](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/upon), and that in this case *upon* is an older (not to say archaic) term used to describe the act of playing on an instrument.

Comment: But is "changed on/upon" correct?

Comment: @drm65: Yes, it is. Compare "Pieces written on the guitar are changed on/upon the piano."

Comment: Yes.  Think of it as "changed [when played] on/upon."

Comment: @Rhodri: Exactly what I was about to post :)

Comment: Don't you think the word "recondite" is rather recondite?  It's recursively autological.  How fun!

Answer (score 0):

*Upon* has the same meaning of *on*. Sometimes it is more formal than *on*, and sometimes it is used in abstract senses.

> It was based upon two principles.

In some cases, *upon* is preferred to *on*, as in the following phrases. For other phrases, using *upon* instead of *on* is not a question of correctness (although there could be some set phrases where *on* is used instead of *upon*).

- once upon a time
- upon my word
- row upon row of seats
- Christmas is almost upon us.

Comment: I do know what "upon" means.  That wasn't my question.

Comment: @drm65 There are few phrases where _upon_ is preferred, such as _once upon the time_; for the other phrases, you can use indifferently one or the other. _Upon_ is sometimes considered more formal, but you cannot say that using it instead of _on_ is correct, or it is not correct. Set phrases are a different case, but I don't think I would talk of correctness, even in that case.

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that I understand the difference between _on_ and _upon_.  My question was about whether _upon_ is used correctly in the poem excerpt I provided.

Comment: @drm65 And to that, I replied.

Comment: Sorry if I'm not being clear - I was _not_ wondering if "on" would have been more correct.  I was wondering if "on/upon" was correct, or if some third possibility was correct.